# Unable to access a declared image by imageTk within a definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have declared an image file within a class and I'm able to show it in the class body. But when I am calling it within a function to show it within the function body it throws an error.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
body=Tk()
ftpim = Image.open('textfile_big.png')
ftpfileimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ftpim)
lbl=Label(body,image=ftpfileimage).pack()
def nextimg():
    cbody=Tk()
    lbl=Label(cbody,image=ftpfileimage).pack()
but=Button(body,command=nextimg,text="show").pack()
body.mainloop()
```

When I'm executing it, however, I have the error `"pyimage1" doesn't exist` :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\My Love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\My Love\Desktop\New Folder\Unknown_Project\Unknown_package\sssss.py", line 10, in nextimg
lbl=Label(cbody,image=ftpfileimage).pack()
File "C:\Users\My Love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2763, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Users\My Love\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Comment: Change from `lbl=Label(...).pack()` to `lbl=Label(...)\n  lbl.pack()`

Comment: No getting same error

Comment: You must call `Tk()` a maximum of *one time* in a program.  Each one is an entirely separate GUI environment, that does not have access to the objects (images, in this case) of another.  To create additional windows, use `Toplevel()` instead.